# Simplify Option creation in Scala to avoid conditions

Tags: scala

Now I create `Option` using `if` condition:

```
if (lastTime > 0) 
  Some(lastTime) 
else 
  None
```

is it possible to simplify such expression?

Comment: I really doubt that two answers with use of "filter/find" are more readable and performant than if condition.

Comment: @om-nom-nom agree with you. readability of original code is much better that mine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Option(lastTime).filter(_ > 0)`

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can add an extension method to `Boolean`s:

```
implicit class BooleanExtension(val bool: Boolean) extends AnyVal {
  def option[T](value: T): Option[T] =
    if (bool) Some(value) else None
}
```

Usage: `(lastTime > 0).option(lastTime)`

And in case you are using the Scalaz library, it already has this extension method (`option`) defined.